# Script doesn't want autoload Facebook-Wall-Module (Joomla)

Tags: facebook, joomla

I try to build a little "social-media-wall" with Joomla 3.4.8. and the "Facebook Wall"-Module (Vers. 8.2) from WebKul.

Example:
On Page 1 I let show the last Post from Rihanna's Facebook-Wall, on Page 2 I let show the last Post from David Guetta's FB-Wall.

It works!!

Now I want to show this two Sites in rotation. Forethat I use a little "Browsershow"-Code. This Code shows this two sites in an iframe. If site 1 ist shown, the Code load/refresh in the background Site 2, and if site 2 is shown, the Code load in the backgroud Site 1.

And now the Problem: On some Desktop-Computers, the browsershow doesnt show the Facebook-Box (only one time directly after the start of the browsershow).
It seems, that the Code cannot load the FB-Box automaticly.

I don't know why. At home, the Box is showing on all Computers (all browsers), but on work, the box is invisible (in all browsers)

Do you have any idea, why? Is there any conflict or problem in the site-code?
Please take a short look at:
http://www.social-studio.de/browsershows/browsershow_2.html

Sorry for my complicated explaining & thank you for help!

Best regards,

Christian

Comment: Please post what's in your browser's web console when the problem manifests

Comment: Please raise a support request at https://webkul.uvdesk.com/  and we will look in to it